# How to generate histogram of Java object lifetimes

Tags: java, tomcat, profiling

I have a Tomcat Java webapp which is thrashing the Java GC when under load. I think this is due to a combination of a large amount of short lived objects along with an unknown amount of moderately long lived objects.

To validate this theory I want to find a tool which will let me determine the object lifetimes for all allocated objects (or every 10th object etc for better performance). Ideally the final output will be a histogram showing the relative number of objects which live for different amounts of time.

I think this tool will likely be built on top of either the Instrumentation API or the JVMTI. If there are no good tools which already do this I would also appreciate suggestions about which of the JVM's interfaces would be best to use when writing such a tool.

Comment: Have you tried JMX + VisualVM? Or Probe?

Comment: Run a static code analyzer on the code also. That might point out some areas of concern.

Comment: A good free analyzer is the Eclipse Memory Analyzer (you don't have to have Eclipse installed).  

After you restart the app does it perform well for a while or does it start thrashing right out of the gate? The latter might indicate you just don't have enough ram available.

Comment: Thanks for these suggestions - I appreciate the alternatives but I'm ideally looking for a tool which gets me a histogram of object lifetimes, ideally by either instance count or instance size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have now started writing a tool to do what I originally asked about. The current code can be found here:

http://wiki.github.com/mchr3k/org.inmemprofiler/

So far I have managed to get a textual histogram of all object allocations by instance count. This does not include array allocations which are handled differently.

I am now working on adding instance size information along with tracking of array allocations by using the JVMTI.

Comment: This tool can now track object sizes and allocation traces.